# How to store content on local and remote server

Tags: java, video

I have writing a program which ask for video file from user. once video is browser by user it is save inside war/content. I do not have any problem to do this. when i want to see the video, i used video tag of html and give the relative path. video come perfectly fine and it can be viewed.

I used the following line of code to resolve the path.

```
    System.setProperty("webapp.root", "C:/solution/totalsolution");
File webappDir = new File(System.getProperty("webapp.root", "./"));

        File webappInfo = new File(webappDir, "war");

        if(!webappInfo.exists()){
            File dir = new File(webappDir, "war");
            if(!dir.exists()){
                if(dir.mkdir()){
                    webappDir = dir;
                }
            }
        }

        webappDir = webappInfo;

        webappInfo = new File(webappDir, "content");

        if(!webappInfo.exists()){
            File dir = new File(webappDir, "content");
            if(!dir.exists() && dir.mkdir()){
                webappDir = dir;
            }
        }


        webappDir = webappInfo;

        if(contentDir != null){
            webappInfo = new File(webappDir, contentDir);

            if(!webappInfo.exists()){
                File dir = new File(webappDir, contentDir);
                if(!dir.exists() && dir.mkdir()){
                    webappDir = dir;
                }
            }

            webappDir = webappInfo; 
        }
```

this program create new folder in specified path like `"C:/solution/totalsolution/war/content/abcd/xysa.mp4"`
when i show any resource then i make relative path like this

```
http://localhost:8080/solution/content/abcd/xysa.mp4
```

till now every thing is ok.But when i extract war file and deploye it into server. 
Then is way failed due to static location in system property.

So can any body tell be the right approch to save data into war folder and right back reading it on local as well as on server to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Do not store it in the war folder but in a separate location (probably designed specifically for this).
2) When getting the file from the user, you need to generate new unique name for this file, and store somewhere (e.g. DB) the mapping from the original file name to the new file name. Then on the disk you store the file under the new name. This is to guarantee your file names are unique (think what happens if two users upload files with the same name).

Comment: can u give any example where we store data in drive and read it using server like tomcat

Comment: @naveen It can be an external i.e. non-web folder (from the point of view of your tomcat) e.g. c:/data/ (Windows) or /data (Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to save data into your webapp; there is no guarantee that this directory will be writable or even unpacked from the jar. Instead, read a property that tells you where to store data saved at runtime.

Comment: i agree that " there is no guarantee that webapp directory will be writable".Infact as per my understanding webapp should not be writable for security reason. But you also said "there is no guarantee that webapp directory will be upacked from jar". Do you mean it may not be exploded directory but deployed as jar file?

Comment: i did the same thing in local machine. But confused how to resolve the server directory structure. Like in my code i store data locally at some where "c:/solution/totalsolution/war/content/uniquefolder/uniquefile.ext". It works perfectly fine. But now i have my tomcat at d: drive when i paste the war file and run the program then file is also written at the same drive. But when i link any content like href="". then server make path like this localhost:8080/solution/content/uniquefolder/uniquefile.ext.

Comment: how i can to go to the drive when i deploy the war file on server

Comment: @MSach Correct: It's entirely acceptable for a container to run an application straight out of a war/ear file.